How to Implement a Lockfile to Prevent Multiple Instances of a Java Application
I am working on a Java application, and I need to ensure that only one instance of the application runs at any given time. I have read that this can be achieved using a lockfile. The idea is that when the application starts, it checks for the existence of a lockfile. If the lockfile exists, an error message should be displayed, and the application should abort. If it does not exist, the application should create the lockfile and proceed.
Could anyone provide guidance or examples on how to implement this functionality in Java? Specifically, I am looking for:

How to check for the existence of a lockfile.

How to create a lockfile.

How to handle the situation where the lockfile already exists (e.g., display an error message and abort the application).

Any potential pitfalls or best practices to consider when using lockfiles.


Additionally, are there other methods or best practices to ensure that only one instance of a Java application is running? Any advice or examples would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you for your help!

Presuming you call the lockfile lockfile.txt and are happy that it is located in the same folder as the java command is run from...
Check existence as follows:
File f = new File("lockfile.txt");
if(f.exists() && !f.isDirectory()) { 
    // tell the user it's running already
    System.exit();
}

Create as follows:
File f = new File("lockfile.txt");
f.createNewFile();
f.deleteOnExit(); // this will cause the file to be deleted on exit

Remove the file on exit.
That's what f.deleteOnExit() mentioned above is for - thanks to @user85421
Pitfall is that the deletion fails and you have to delete the lockfile manually. Or some naughty user adds a lockfile.txt when the app is not running to prevent it starting.

maybe be interesting: File#deleteOnExit

Thanks @user85421. Updated my answer.

It is possible for two applications to reach f.createNewFile() at same time. Using new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw"), getChannel() and tryLock() means that code is more resilient, and also deals with the lingering lock file problem.
